# Gentoo startup error (D-BUS)

Tags: linux, boot, gentoo, dbus

When I start my PC with Gentoo everything goes ok until it reaches

```
    INIT: Entering runlevel: 3
    ...
    Starting D-BUS system messagebus
```

It just stops booting here.

What might be wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

That most probably mean dbus did not daemonize. Take a peek at /etc/init.d/dbus and figure out how to force dbus to daemonize.

Should look something like:

```
start-stop-daemon --start --pidfile /var/run/dbus.pid --exec /usr/bin/dbus-daemon -- --system
```